# Verifying multiple emails from array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a query that I am not too sure how I can make it work

I have a form where the end users can add multiple email fields using jquery and it places each text input into an array

I have created some code that verifies each array key and fills an array with a number for verification purposes

Here is the code for verifying the POST:

```
// Collect and verify attached email
if(isset($_POST["email"])){

    // set var for collecting email and store as null
    $emailfields ="";

    // start verify loop
    foreach($_POST["email"] as $key => $email)
    {
        // Filter var email to comfirm it is an email
        $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
         if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false)
        {
            $emailcheckarray[] = 1;
        } else {
            $emailcheckarray[] = 0;
        }
            // Create a string for later
            $emailfields .= $email .",";

        }

    // Verify Array contains value
    if (!in_array('1', $emailcheckarray, true)) 
    {
    $emailverification = 1;
    } else {
    $emailverification = 0;
    }    
}

echo $emailfields;
echo $emailverification;
```

Now this works it fills the array $emailcheckarray with 1 1 1 1 1 if the emails are valid depending on how many inputs the user uses.

Is there a way that I can get the in_array to only work with all keys being the same as currently if one of the keys are 0 it still outputs $emailverification as 1 if the user enters 1 valid email and the rest invalid when I want it to be 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just omit the `in_array` if you set the verification to 0 during the loop when any of the checks fails. So start with a value of 1 as you have no failures yet:

```
$emailverification = 1; // added
// start verify loop
foreach($_POST["email"] as $key => $email)
{
    // Filter var email to comfirm it is an email
    $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) !== false)
    {
        $emailcheckarray[] = 1;
    } else {
        $emailcheckarray[] = 0;
        $emailverification = 0; // added
    }
    // Create a string for later
    $emailfields .= $email .",";
}
```

... and then at the end of the loop you have the correct value.

Comment: Thanks this makes perfect sense

Comment: Thanks, note that I was a bit too quick in removing the second call to filter_var. I didn't notice the difference in the argument passed. Reverted that.

Comment: This seems more verbose than it needs to be.  Couldn't the `if` just be `if ($email !== false)`? You're doing the xact same thing above....

Comment: @cale_b, I thought the same thing, but look at the second argument of *filter_var* :-)

Comment: Ah! Hard to see, but very important distinction! Nice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use functions such as `array_map` and `array_filter` to get an array of all the valid emails.

```
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $sanitized_emails = array_map(function ($email) {
        return filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    }, $_POST['email']);
    $valid_emails = array_filter($sanitized_emails, function($email) {
        return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    });
    $emailfields = implode(',', $sanitized_emails);
}
```

Then you just have to compare the size of the two tabs.

```
$emailverification = 0;
if (count($emails) == count($valid_emails)) {
    $emailverification = 1;
}
```

Comment: Nice! How would you add the population of *$emailcheckarray*? Maybe OP still needs them... Note also that original code concatenated the sanitized emails, not only the valid ones.

Comment: I assumed `$emailcheckarray` was just an intermediate variable, but you could get it the same way as you get `$sanitized_emails` : just change the returning line to `return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? 1 : 0;`

Answer (score 0):

Check the affirmative for zero:

```
if (in_array('0', $emailcheckarray, true)) {
    $emailverification = 0;
} else {
    $emailverification = 1;
}
```

If you don't have any zeros, that means they're all ones.